# I'm stuck in one place and can't move in Pokémon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

Once I was playing Pokémon Go while riding a bus. Suddenly the game froze - that sometimes happens. Later I opened a game and now it shows that I'm in that location where it has frozen previously. There's no "no GPS signal found" notification, and I can even catch Pokémon at that place.

I've checked my GPS through google maps - it shows me my true location.

(My device is SG S5 with custom ROM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to server strain, when a lot of people are playing at the same time, the servers may not work properly again for everyone. If, even after restarting your phone, this continues, try again later. If it continues, there might be a bigger issue.

Comment: Well it's about week for now, so I think this is really "a bigger issue"...

Answer (score -1):

On Apple’s iPhones, users report that Pokemon GO freezes consistently when simply trying to complete a capture. Why this happens is unclear, but Reddit users report that switching their LTE connection in the Cellular settings from on to off solves the problem. Without LTE the game can still use the rest of the cellular network to connect.

Users with other smartphones report the issue happens on Android too, and that force closing the app usually results in the creature being added to their inventory. If you decide to do this. Tap on the icon of you in the bottom-left corner, then open the Journal to see if your capture was successful after a freeze.